# angularjs loaded, but not called

Tags: css, angularjs

Using https://github.com/danprince/ng-picky plugin

HTML is

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ngPicky">


     <div class="category_header forum_category" style="background:{{color | toHex}};"></div>
  <picker color="color"></picker>
```

both ng-picky.js and ng-picky.css are loaded, so is Angular. But the colour picker it is supposed to display is not shown. I guess css and js has not been called. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any error in the js console of the browser?

Comment: I just tried the sample in plucker & is working just fine, compare the following with your implementation http://plnkr.co/edit/b5EeWUkJ1hBczditme2Q?p=preview

Comment: @melsaqqa  I use ng-controller as ngPicky instead of PickyController you used. Also I do not have script.js or style.css. Where did you get those files ?

Comment: Please add your js code where you declare `myApp`.

Comment: Kindly refer to the github file attached. I use ng-picky.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the module `ngPicky` as a dependency of your app. The declaration of your app should look like the following:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngPicky']);
```

Except if you defined a controller named `ngPicky`, the following has no sense:

```
ng-controller="ngPicky"
```

Comment: After loading `angular.js` and `ng-picky.js` you should load your script file(s), for example `app.js`. You might want to go through the tutorial from [the angular website](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)